# MacVim: difference in syntax highlighting in terminal and GUI

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, macvim

I installed MacVim with homebrew, and specified the option to override system vim. It can be confirmed by looking at the version of vim in terminal.

However, I don't understand why the terminal (mac)vim and the gui has different color in syntax highlighting. And I prefer the GUI's coloring. Why the difference and can I set the terminal's syntax highlight the same as the GUI's?

Terminal:[image: Terminal MacVim]

GUI: [image: GUI MacVim]

Comment: answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112972/macvim-gets-all-settings-from-vimrc-but-not-the-colors-and-i-have-to-source